# In a closed monoidal category, is $[-,-]$ always a bifunctor?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories

We say a monoidal category $\mathcal V=(\mathcal V_0,\otimes,I,a,l,r)$ is *closed* if the endofunctor $-⊗Y$ has a right adjoint $[Y,-]$, called the *exponential*, for every $Y$. The object $[Y,Z]$ for objects $Y,Z\in\mathcal V_0$ is also called *internal hom* of $Y$ and $Z$. This suggests one can make it a bifunctor $\mathcal V_0^{\text{op}}\times\mathcal V_0\to\mathcal V_0$. Indeed, given any $f:Y'\to Y$, one may define $[f,Z]:[Y,Z]\to[Y',Z]$ as the unique arrow satisfying
$$\varepsilon^{Y'}_Z([f,Z]⊗1)=ε^Y_Z(1⊗f)$$
where $e^Y:[Y,Z]⊗Y\Rightarrow Z$ denotes the counit of the adjunction given by $Y$. It is not difficult to show that this defines a contravariant functor $[-,Z]$ for fixed $Z$.

However, in order for $[-,-]$ to be a **bifunctor**, it needs to satisfy the compatibility condition
$$[Y',g][f,Z] = [f,Z'][Y,g] : [Y,Z]\to[Y',Z']\qquad (1)$$
Now one can compute
$$\begin{align}
ε([Y',g]⊗1)([f,Z]⊗1) & = gε([f,Z]⊗1) \\
                      & = gε(1⊗f) \\
                      & = ε([Y,g]⊗1)(1⊗f) \\
                      & = ε(1⊗f)([Y,g]⊗1) \\
& = ε([f,Z']⊗1)([Y,g]⊗1)
\end{align}
$$
as arrows $[Y,Z]⊗ Y' \to Z'$
Unless I've made some mistake, this verifies that their adjuncts satisfy (1).

However, I found it nowhere mentioned that $[-,-]$ is really a bifunctor, neither in literature nor in the nLab. Could someone confirm that my reasoning is correct and/or give a reference for this fact? Thanks.

Comment: It is well known and considered obvious. If you really want a citeable justification, look at Theorem 3 in [CWM, Ch. IV, §7].

Comment: And for a generalization to n-variables, see Theorem 2.2 [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~eriehl/mates.pdf#page=16).

Comment: @ZhenLin: I wouldn't call it obvious. It requires some verification, and while I was trying to figure out the necessary diagram chasing, I wasn't sure if it's true in the first place. I would have expected it to be mentioned somewhere. But thanks for the reference, I'll look into it in order to see how this is a special case.

Comment: Ah, I see Mac Lane mentiones this in [CWM, Ch. IV, §6] for Cartesian closed categories.